# Python Kivy: how to call a function on button click?

Tags: python, function, button, kivy

i'm pretty new at using kivy library.

I have an app.py file and an app.kv file , my problem is that I can't call a function on button press.

app.py:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Launch(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Launch, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def say_hello(self):
        print "hello"


class App(App):
    def build(self):
        return Launch()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().run()
```

app.kv:

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

<Launch>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            size:(80,80)
            size_hint:(None,None)
            text:"Click me"
            on_press: say_hello
```

Answer (score 13):

## Mode:`.kv`

It's very simple, `say_hello` belongs to the `Launch` class so in order to use it in your `.kv` file you have to write `root.say_hello`. Note that `say_hello` is a function that you want to execute so you don't have to forget the `()` ---> `root.say_hello()`.

Also, if `say_hello` were in `App` class you should use `App.say_hello()` because it belongs to the app. (Note: even if your App class were `class MyFantasicApp(App):` it would always be `App.say_hello()` or `app.say_hello()` I don't remember, sorry).

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

<Launch>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            size:(80,80)
            size_hint:(None,None)
            text:"Click me"
            on_press: root.say_hello()
```

## Mode: `.py`

You can `bind` the function.

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button # You would need futhermore this
class Launch(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Launch, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        mybutton = Button(
                            text = 'Click me',
                            size = (80,80),
                            size_hint = (None,None)
                          )
        mybutton.bind(on_press = self.say_hello) # Note: here say_hello doesn't have brackets.
        Launch.add_widget(mybutton)

    def say_hello(self):
        print "hello"
```

Why use `bind`? Sorry, no idea. But you it's used in [the kivy guide](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.button.html).

Comment: You don't have to bind it if you make a separate `MyButton` class, where you would define a method `on_press()`. Probably too much work, unless you have other things to do with the Button.

Answer (score 3):

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.button import Button

from kivy.uix.label import Label

class Test(App):

def press(self,instance):
    print("Pressed")
def build(self):
    butt=Button(text="Click")
    butt.bind(on_press=self.press) #dont use brackets while calling function
    return butt

Test().run()
```

Comment: very naughty variable names indeed!

Answer (score 2):

`say_hello` is a method of the Launch class. In your kv rule, the Launch class is the root widget, so it can be accessed using the `root` keyword:

```
on_press: root.say_hello()
```

Note also that you have to actually call the function, not just write its name - everything to the right of the colon is normal Python code.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the solution utilizing the bind function (given by Ender Look) will lead to the following error:

```
TypeError: pressed() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

To solve this issue you have to allow the say_hello() module to accept the touch input as well, although it isn't needed.

Comment: Please clarify more your answer. If you use the parts of the code that you don't believe that work, it will be more helpful. Thanks

Comment: @EnriqueBet I tried the code above and kept getting the error I mentioned. I allowed say_hello() to accept another parameter to account for the Touch event and then everything worked fine. Is there another explanation? I'm new to Kivy and was just challenging myself to not use kv files, so that it would be easier to use whatever I learn here with other OOP languages.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone is looking for a pure Python approach here is a general example.

To call a function without arguments:

```py
def my_function(instance):
   ...

my_button.bind(on_press=my_function)
```

To call a function with arguments:

```py
from functools import partial

def my_function(instance, myarg):
   ...

my_button.bind(on_press=partial(my_function,"a string"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to add function to any element in Kivy just use logic like here.

In your .py file:

```
class LoginButton(Button):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text = "Login"

    def login(self):
        print("logged_in")
```

And then in .kv file:

```
LoginButton:
            id: "login"
            on_press: self.login()
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 500, 50
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
```

It works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

function with object as argument in kv-file

in kv:

```
on_press: root.say_hello(self)
```

in py:

```
def say_hello(self,obj):
    print(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

you just added root before say_hello() function.
like this

```
on_press:
    root.say_hello()
```

it should working