# Call def from one class to another class in python

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have two file `demo.py` and `demo.kv`.
Can anyone tell me how to call function from one class to another class?I want to call `def calculate(self):` from `def on_text(self, text_input, value):`.Now i am using code

```
def on_text(self, text_input, value):
    App.get_running_app().User.calculate()
```

But it gives error AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'User'

demo.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
Window.size = (500, 400)

class User(Popup):
    total_value = ObjectProperty(None)

    def add_more(self):
        self.ids.rows.add_row()

    def calculate(self):
        rows = self.ids.rows
        total = 0
        for row in rows.children:
            text = row.ids.number_input.text
            total += int(text) if text != "" else 0  # validate if the entry is not empty
        self.total_value.text = str(total)

class Row(BoxLayout):
    col_data = ListProperty(["?", "?", "?", "?", "?"])
    button_text = StringProperty("")
    col_data3 = StringProperty("")
    col_data4 = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Row, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.number_input.bind(text=self.on_text)

    def on_text(self, text_input, value):
        print('Calling')
        App.get_running_app().User.calculate()



class Rows(BoxLayout):
    row_count = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Rows, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_row()

    def add_row(self):
        self.row_count += 1
        self.add_widget(Row(button_text=str(self.row_count)))


class rv(BoxLayout):
    data_items = ListProperty([])
    mode = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(rv, self).__init__(**kwargs)


    def add(self):
        self.mode = "Add"
        popup = User()
        popup.open()


class MainMenu(BoxLayout):
    content_area = ObjectProperty()

    def display(self):
        self.rv = rv()
        self.content_area.add_widget(self.rv)

class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('demo.kv')
        return MainMenu()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

demo.kv

```
<Row>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    height: 40

    Button:
        text: root.button_text
        size_hint_x: None
        top: 200

    TextInput:
        text: root.col_data3
        width: 300
    TextInput:
        id: number_input
        text: root.col_data4
        width: 300
        input_filter: 'int'


<Rows>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    orientation: "vertical"

<User>:
    id: user
    total_value:total_value
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding : 20, 5


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            #padding : 10, 10
            spacing: 10, 10
            size: 450, 40
            size_hint: None, None

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .2
                text: "Number"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'bottom'
                halign: 'center'

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .4
                text: "name"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'bottom'
                halign: 'center'

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .4
                text: "Value"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'bottom'
                halign: 'center'




        ScrollView:
            Rows:
                id: rows

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            padding : 10, 5
            spacing: 10, 10
            size: 200, 40
            size_hint: None, None

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .7
                text: "Total value"

            TextInput:
                id: total_value
                on_focus:root.test()



        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint_x: .2
            size_hint_y: .2

            Button:
                text: "+Add More"
                on_press: root.add_more()

<rv>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Button:
            size_hint: .25, .03
            text: "+Add"
            on_press: root.add()

        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 25
            cols: 3

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"

<MenuButton@Button>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5
    size : (100, 40)
    size_hint : (None, None)
    background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
    background_normal: ''
    color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1
    border: (0, 10, 0, 0)

<MainMenu>:
    content_area: content_area

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing : 10

        BoxLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            size_hint_y: 2

            MenuButton:
                text: 'Menu'
                size : (50, 12)
                on_release: root.display()

        BoxLayout:
            id: content_area
            size_hint_y: 30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this problem without accessing the tree of kivy hierarchies is using global variables, but it is advisable not to abuse this type of variables since the errors generated by its misuse are difficult to trace.

```
[...]
class Row(BoxLayout):
    [...]

    def on_text(self, text_input, value):
        print('Calling')
        popup.calculate()

class rv(BoxLayout):
    [...]
    def add(self):
        self.mode = "Add"
        global popup
        popup = User()
        popup.open()
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be a duplicate of this question: [Im New on kivy Python classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48325676/im-new-on-kivy-python-classes/48327827#48327827)

Firstly:

```
class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('demo.kv')
        return MainMenu()
```

This is a bit unnecessary, you can instead do:

```
class demo(App):

    def build(self):
        return MainMenu()
```

App's search for a kv file with a lowercase name equal to the App's name.

Secondly:

```
<User>:
    id: user
    total_value:total_value
```

This is not how you use ids in the kivy Widgets. When you define a Kivy Widget, ie:

```
class KivyWidgetName(KivyLayout):
    pass

<KivyWidgetName>:
```

You're creating a class. When you add your custom widget to a parent Widget, you are creating an *Object* of that KivyWidget Class. Sometimes however if you're making more than one, you need to give them ids so their parent can separate them from each other.

ie:

```
<RootWidget>:
    KivyWidgetName:
        id: first_instance
    KivyWidgetName:
        id: second_instance
```

So now RootWidget can access two different versions of the class, if it wants to access the first one, it can do:

```
self.ids.first_instance
```

You can also access them by the index number in which they appear, so this
can also be done by:

```
self.ids[1]
```

However explicit is typically better than implicit

Thirdly, you had the right idea to this:

```
App.get_running_app().User.calculate()
```

but it should actually be something like this:

```
App.get_running_app().root.ids.[INSERTID]
```

So in this case, you're getting the root widget of app (which is ), then you need to use the ids to get to the proper address.

For example, take this:

:
    User:
        id: 'user_one'
    User:
        id: 'user_two'

To access the user calculate function, you can do this:

```
App.get_running_app().root.ids.user_one.calculate
```

If you however have a number of children, you'll have to seek all of their ids until you find user:

For example:

```
<TestWidget>:
    User:
        id: 'user_one'
    User:
        id: 'user_two'

<RootWidget>:
    TestWidget:
        id: 'test_one'
    TestWidget:
        id: 'test_two'
```

So to get to user one of test two, you can do this:

App.get_running_app().root.ids.test_two.ids.user_one.calculate

You might need to re-arrange your rootwidget to be something else that just contains your main menu to help you with this but that decision is up to you ultimately.